# replacing brackets

Tags: regex, vim, awk, sed

I would like to replace all occurrences of "exp( ... )" with "Exp[ ... ]" in the following (essentially changing from Matlab to Mathematica syntax):

```
exp(-(pi*k2*2i)/3)*(v9/4 + (3^(1/2)*(v8/2 + (3^(1/2)*v9)/2))/2 + (3^(1/2)*v8)/12) + exp((pi*k2*2i)/3)*(v9/4 + (3^(1/2)*(v8/2 + (3^(1/2)*v9)/2))/2 + (3^(1/2)*v8)/12) ...
```

Is it possible to automate this with vim, sed, or awk? The trick is not replacing all "(" with "[", only the ones that occur immediately after exp and the corresponding pair.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do that with a `vim` macro.

Let's clear the `a` register by pressing `qaq`. ( In case if any previous operations are recorded, we can clear them)

Start a macro recording by pressing `qa`.
Search for `exp(` by typing`/exp(/e`. this will put the cursor at `(`.
Press `%` to move to its closing bracket. Press `r]` to replace it with `]`.
Now, press `N` to move to `exp(`. Press `r[` to replace it with `[`. Press `@a` to recursively replace all such instances. Press `q` to stop recording.

Now, you can press`@a` to play the macro and it will replace everywhere.

Comment: If you want to use a little automation, you can enter `:%s/exp(//gn` to get a count of the number of times `exp(...)` occurs in your code. Say it's `n`. Then type `n@a` to run the macro `n` times and make all the changes at once.

Comment: You need to rectify `/exp/e` to `/exp/e+1` or `/exp(/e` so you can put the cursor at **(**

Comment: @Meninx  I have given `exp(` in the answer to search for `/exp(/e`. While typing I missed `(` here. Thanks for rectifying. I will correct it now.

Comment: +1 for correct use of recursive macros.  Although you probably want to clear the `a` register before starting recording.  Just run `qaq` first.

Answer (score 0):

In the following sed script (brackreplace) we are:

- `exp(` →  `Exp§`
- hide balanced  `(...)` → `«...»`  (if they have no `"()§"` inside)
- `Exp§...)` → `Exp[...]`
- restoring hidden parentesis

```
#!/bin/sed -zf 

s/exp(/Exp§/g                    # (1) protect        exp( →  Exp§
s/(\([^()§]*\))/«\1»/g           # (2) hide balanced  (...) → «...» 

s/Exp§\([^()§]*\))/Exp[\1]/g     # (3) Exp§...) → Exp[...]
s/«/(/g                          # restore protected parentesis
s/»/)/g
```

This cover your example; repeat line (2) if you expect deeper () inside exp(...).

After `chmod`, this command may be used in command line or inside the editor. Example with vim:

```
:%!bracketreplace
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Sibi's answer, but just a subtle change, you should use `` to jump back to the matching brace instead of `N`. otherwise it doesn't work with this pattern: `exp(...exp(...))`